# Android Localise In Spanish

Tags: android, localization

I'm in the process of localising an app and the three languages are German, French, and Spanish. German and French are fine. I created the `values-fr`, and `values-de` folders with the string.xml. These work and show a french and german flag attached to the strings.xml in Android Studio however the `values-es` for spanish doesn't show the flag and doesn't work when the app is running.

I've tried `values-es`, `values-es_ES`, `values-es-ES`, and none have worked.

Comment: values-es works just fine to me. Where it doesnt work, on a device, emulator or layout preview,

Comment: @gian1200 I'm going to kick myself in the future but while trying all these things I forget to check the values part. Turns out I deleted the s while renaming.

Comment: Try a double kick to get the extra points for  a combo. :) happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device supports the Spanish locale, try being more specific with the qualifiers.

For eg: use "values-es-rUS" if you are targeting the US market and the like.

Comment: Not really needed. `values-es` means "standard Spanish", or "common Spanish", which is the default one and comes from the originating country, Spain in this case. It will be well understood and accepted in Mexico, Argentina, Uruguay, ... and every part in the world where Spanish is spoken.

Comment: This can be needed for complex translations, but for most simple settings labels etc a single translation for spanish is adequate.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I agree with JamesKraw. Mexico is a good example where you would use values-es-rUS since the language there is different from what values-es would be.

Comment: @JigneshShah But I think that MExicans will still understand their motherlanguage, I mean the language that has been the matrix for the **dialect** they speak. An Austrian or a Switzerian still understands **real German**, as well a Belgian or a Lichtensteiner. And a Canadian still understands both **real French** and **real English** (as do Americans - for English)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I think what we're more talking about is user experience. Most of these places will also understand English just fine, or at least enough to use the app which is why localisation isn't always implemented. However localising into each native region language can be better for a cleaner, smoother user experience.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk Well, if you are Mexican there are chances that you understand English. If you are Bolivian, maybe not. But there are chances that you understand **real Spanish**

Comment: Can someone explain why it's `es_rUS` and not `es_US`?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to always check the values folder has been spelt correct.